# Excel Creates an External Link to Add-In when Transporting Worksheet Between Users

Tags: microsoft-excel

Simply stated, I have a formula in a worksheet that I made on one computer:

```
=setChartAxis("Template","Chart 2","Min","Y","Primary",(Template!C4 - 0.5))
```

The setChartAxis function itself is from an Excel Add-In. The formula works fine on my computer, but the moment I copy the worksheet to another computer and open it there, the formula changes, inserting the original path of the Add-In (from the first computer) into the formula as such:

```
='C:\Users\myname\path\addin.xlam'!setChartAxis("Template","Chart 2","Min","Y","Primary",(Template!C4 - 0.5))
```

This breaks the formula, despite the fact that the second computer does have the Add-In installed.

Editing the path out of the formula works, but I need a way to get everything to work without having to do that each time.